# Android book for custom ROM building

Tags: android

I'm looking for a book or other resource which gives me a good overview over the Android system.
Things I'm looking for:

- how to define preinstalled apps / widgets
- how to add drivers for sensor data (e.g. accelerometer)
- how to configure display parameters

Every recommendation is welcome as I didn't find anything yet.

Comment: I think the forums on [XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/) might be a good place to start.

Comment: I know that site and it's in fact a good place, but still valuable information is mostly scattered around the forum and not always easy to find.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry this is a late answer, but recently I've stumbled on a very helpful set of videos on this subject from Marko Gargenta -- it was very helpful to me understanding the different portions of android and how to get started with creating a custom ROM image:

Android Internals Part 1: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0
and Part 2: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFqELLB1Kk8

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a few books devoted to android system.

1. Embedded Android by Karim Yaghmour
2. Android Forensics: Investigation, Analysis and Mobile Security for Google Android by Andrew Hoog.

Marakana videos are useful also.

Answer (score 2):

- source.android.com - you should have done some build (to deal with common errors) before thinking about how to customize it.
- This youtube playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLUXPxxJc5c&list=PLtw7MVCFtZkTg93Ofr7KTusbSSauVu6bi is a very good start.
  He introduces how to build a custom Android service there.
- Also Embedded Android by Karim Yaghmour. (Everything covered from basics).

P/S: If you have one device, and you want to port pure Android (AOSP, Cyanogenmod) to it, then you kinda have to learn by experience at some point due to some of the source code not released by vendors.
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of such books, however, you can have clues on what you are asking in the source code. All these are done in the product definition.

You have a good example in ./device/samsung/crespo (which is the product definition for the Nexus S).

You define preinstalled apps by modifying the PRODUCT_PACKAGES variables, in the Makefile for your product.

Drivers are both done in the kernel, and in libsensors for the accelerometer, and every other sensors.